# Different format show for pages that have been created with contextual filter

Tags: views

Using *view contextual filter* and *taxonomy term* that we can design our site. But how can I customize each page differently. For example my site has three sections such as *Product*, *Learning*,  *Home*. I use arguments as an option to dynamically create a page, However I would like to have different format show for those that I want (Home and Product).
Is there any solution for this approach or should I create the views separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want each content type to look unique when displayed in your view you can already do that.

You could use the view row style 'Content' to display the content with the 'teaser' view mode (or whatever), you can then change how the teaser view mode looks for each content type in the display settings for that content type:

/admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT_TYPE/display/teaser

The [Display Suite module](https://drupal.org/project/ds) extends this if you need more flexibility here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what kind of changes you are looking to make - by default you are going to have unique body classes automatically added to the page that you can use for simple CSS changes.

If it's something more complex than CSS you might want to consider a solution such as [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) or [Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels). It is hard to say without knowing exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Freddy. All I want is to define multiple style and base on them create different content type so when I use the arguments, the view gather all contents together to show and each content has its own style. from now on my site is totally dynamic and I just need to add content type for my client and they are free to use them in each page. I Hope that I explain it clearly. Can I use these tree module together (Display Suite, Panels, View)?